ValidationPipe doesn't transform string to number
I use: @UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true })) to transform query param criteria to specific types, but it doesn't work for numbers, can you explain me why?
Version of @bx/nestjs-commons - 9.4.0.
Not working version:
@Get()
@UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true }))
@ApiPageableParams()
@ApiPagedResponse(DeliveryReadModel)
@ApiCriteriaParams(new DeliveryListCriteria().criteriaMapping)
async getDelivery(
  @AuthUser() userDetails: UserDetails,
  @Query() criteria: DeliveryListCriteria,
  @Query() pageable: Pageable
): Promise<PagedModel<DeliveryReadModel>> {
  return this.deliveryService.get(
    criteria,
    pageable
  );
}

export class DeliveryListCriteria {
  mode: number[];
  calculatedLength?: number;  
}

Working version:
@Get()
@UsePipes(
  new ValidationPipe({
    transform: true,
    transformOptions: {
      enableImplicitConversion: true,
    },
  })
)
@ApiPageableParams()
@ApiPagedResponse(DeliveryReadModel)
@ApiCriteriaParams(new DeliveryListCriteria().criteriaMapping)
async getDelivery(
  @AuthUser() userDetails: UserDetails,
  @Query() criteria: DeliveryListCriteria,
  @Query() pageable: Pageable
): Promise<PagedModel<DeliveryReadModel>> {
  return this.deliveryService.get(
    criteria,
    pageable
  );
}

export class DeliveryListCriteria {
  @ApiProperty({
    type: [Number],
  })
  @IsOptional()
  @Type(() => Number)
  mode: number[];
  @ApiProperty({
    format: 'float',
  })
  calculatedLength?: number;  
}


In the second version, the following changes ensure proper transformation:
transformOptions: { enableImplicitConversion: true }

This option allows ValidationPipe to implicitly convert types based on the destination type in the DTO or class. In this case, it converts strings to numbers or arrays of numbers without needing explicit @Type decorators.
Documentation: ValidationPipe Options - transformOptions
Decorators like @Type(() => Number):

This explicitly tells class-transformer how to convert incoming query parameters to the intended type, making sure that arrays like ['1', '2'] is converted to [1, 2].
Documentation: @Type Decorator - class-transformer
But the first example by default the enableImplicitConversion is set to false
and this prevent the convertion of the param criteria
